# why does the following title end "...守られる" and not "守られている"? just to save space?

Tags: verbs, passive-voice

I read the title of the article [キタシロサイ、地球にたった1匹のオス、24時間体制で守られる](http://www.huffingtonpost.jp/2015/04/15/last-male-northern-white-rhin_n_7067626.html?utm_hp_ref=japan) as
"The last male rhino on earth **is being protected** by a system that is active 24-hrs per day."

The " *...is being protected...* " makes me want to say "...守られ **ている** "

1. Were the title: "キタシロサイ、地球にたった1匹のオス、24時間体制で守られ **ている** ", how would the meaning change?
2. Were space not an issue, would the continuous tense have been used?

Comment: It's `northern white rhino`, not just `rhino`. Other species of rhinos have much more males, fortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is ***headline grammar***, not "regular" grammar.  Words are often omitted intentionally in article headlines in Japanese just as in English.

In English, you would see "[Name] Shot Dead" instead of "[Name] Has Been Shot Dead" as a headline, would you not?

> 1.Were the title: "キタシロサイ、地球にたった1匹のオス、24時間体制で守られ ている ", how would the meaning change?

The meaning would stay the same, but it would sound pretty awkward as a headline; It is just too long.

(For fairness, I wonder why you did not mention the absence of a subject marker as well.  That, too, is intentional.  No は/が in headlines, generally.)

> 2.Were space not an issue, would the continuous tense have been used?

No, for the reason I stated above, it would not have.

Comment: "匹" was the counter in the title, but "頭" was the counter in the article. That seems inconsistent but not important I think..